# Run Automated Offline Tasks

Tags: python, web

I have a Python Script that every time I run it, collects data from different sites, stores them into a file and than runs some analysis.

What I want to do next is to somehow install Python and all the packages that I need on a server for example and create a task, let`s say that everyday at 3 p.m, the code I have written executes without me being around and the data and results should be stored into a table.

My questions would be is this is doable?

Comment: This question is out of scope for stackoverflow. The first part is simple. Use [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) for scheduled tasks. It's installed on all unix and linux distros. Suggestions for server hosting is very off topic here. It's subjective and answers get outdated very quickly. (I would probably use a DigitalOcean droplet, but that totally depends on your experience with linux etc.)

Comment: Yes, it is. You can run python tasks from a cron entry.

Comment: Have a look as the raspberry pi computer (priced at less than €40). Its default Raspbian operating system comes with python installed and is a perfect, low cost server for web monitoring... as it doesn't use much energy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to do this. if you are on a server running some form of linux you can use crontab. As for server hostage, I don't know of any free servers but there is always servers for small fees.